# Saving multiple objects to plist and somehow sorting them in to categories

Tags: xcode, plist

So I am currently making a scanApp where it is necessarry to sort different objects in to different categories. So when the user scans a code and gets the result text the result should be saved into the plist file with that category.

This is my approach currently.

```
    values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:resultText.text, nil];
        [values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];

- (NSString *) saveFilePath {
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"savefile.plist"];
}
```

It is the way that I've learnt, but how can I save things with (keys maybe) so that I can sort them.

Also how can I read the items with just that specific category.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Instead of writing the array to plist.write NSDictionary to that.

Comment: Oh, but if I ass the items to a NSDictionary can I add keys to the object aswell?

Comment: @bubblez : Yes you can add keys to everything in NSDictionary